# Cannot start Rails Server due to Tzinfo gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm starting to learn Ruby on Rails but whenever I put the command "rails server", this is the stack trace I get:

```
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-1.2.1/lib/tzinto/data_source.rb:182:in `rescue in create_default_data_source': No source of timezone data could be found. (TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound)
Please refer to http://tzinfo.github.io/datasourcenotfound for help resolving this error
```

Can anybody help me?!

I'm using 64 bit Windows 8.1 with Rails 4.1.4

Comment: There's a link right in there for you to go to (the github link).  Also in the future please paste the errors

Answer (score 2):

Try this I had to add two gems to get the server to start..

```
gem 'tzinfo-data'
gem 'tzinfo'

# for 64 bit windows:
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]
```

Then `bundle install`.

Comment: this is what is suggested on the page of the link in the error message

Comment: I already have those two gems installed.

Comment: @user3510806 :  can you please edit your question which version of Rails and on which OS you are working? read [this link](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo/wiki/Resolving-TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound-Errors) properly..It will solve your issue

Comment: @jigfox : yup..you are right :)

Comment: @Gagan I edited and added the version.

Comment: oh good..you can upvote my answer if it helpful to you..

Answer (score 2):

From the [link](http://tzinfo.github.io/datasourcenotfound):

> If you are using a 64-bit version of Ruby on Windows, then add
>   :x64_mingw to the list of platforms as follows:

```
gem install 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]
```